# Can't get order with OrderRepositoryInterface

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, sales-order, programmatically

I have an order in sales_order with entity_id = 1 and increment_id = 000000001.

Both ways of trying to get this order fails with the same response.

```
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter('increment_id', '000000001')
            ->create();

$orderList = $this->_orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
```

and

```
$orderList = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);
```

Any idea why do these throw the following exception?

```
{
    "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "orderId",
        "fieldValue": "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder` and `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface`?

Comment: Yeah. But I am using Webkul's extension so that there can be multiple vendors. Then I use token authentication for the API, but they need to use customer authentication and cannot access or modify the sales_order table. Now I am looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was authenticated with a customer token, and customers don't have access to that resource (editing it at least).

I logged in as admin and am now able to change orders.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code**

```
$order_id = 000000001;
$order_data = $this->orderRepository->get($order_id);
if (!empty($order_data)) {
    foreach ($order_data->getAllItems() as $value) {
        echo "Product Name: ".$value->getName()." Product ID:  ".$value->getProductId();
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Nope... I get the exact same response

Comment: try to pass order id insted of increment id